# Override Gmail Image Cache (or set a short time limit) for time-sensitive images

Tags: php, email, caching, gmail

We run a popular online marketplace and am experiencing issues with Google's new "Image Cache" service. We publish alerts via email with an image that tells the viewer whether the alert is still valid. If it is, its green and "Available". If its not, its grey and "Unavailable".

The problem we are having is that, when the recipient opens the email, Google fetches the image. It is usually "Available" right then, as it is usually opened very quickly after being sent.

However, when they open the email a second time, it shows "Available". They click the link, thinking they can still claim and take ownership of the alert, but find that is is actually no longer available. We are getting emails and bug reports of it being broken, but its actually a by-product of Google's new Caching service.

Everything worked before, and it still continues to work in other emails, like Outlook.com and Yahoo!. We send expiration headers and a "no-cache" header (which is why the other emails work) but cant seem to have Google check for a change.

Any ideas? Were really scratching our heads with this one. And we don't even know who at Google to talk to about this!

Comment: You're more than likely our of luck. This is a really long shot, but Chrome doesn't cache images with parameters in the url - maybe this will apply to at least the the time limit on Gmail caching. Worth a try...

Answer (score 2):

In short: no, it's not possible. You'd have to change the image url, which - of course - does not work in an email that has been sent. Don't bother asking someone at Gmail - they won't hear you. It also doesn't help your users to turn off the new "Always display external images" setting, because Gmail would still check and cache the graphics. So by now, marketers will have to live with not beeing able to use dynamic realtime images like countdowns, timers, or a product status in Gmail reliably.